# Visual Basic - Taking user input, storing in array, and displaying in Windows Forms

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

I did some java programming last year, but I've started Visual Basic this year and for some reason cannot wrap my head around Windows Forms Apps.

It is a homework assignment, here is the question:

Write a program that accepts five input values and stores them into an array. The program should display those five numbers in reverse order using a loop. The program should then use a function calculate the average of the five numbers, then display all the number in the array that are larger than the average of the five numbers.

Here is the code I have written so far, any help to finish this program would be greatly appreciated

Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub outputButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles outputButton.Click

    'Variables
    Dim fiveNumbers(4) As Integer

    If IsNumeric(FirstNumTextBox.Text) And IsNumeric(SecondNumTextBox.Text) _
        And IsNumeric(ThirdNumTextBox.Text) And IsNumeric(FourthNumTextBox.Text) _
        And IsNumeric(FifthNumTextBox.Text) Then

        fiveNumbers(0) = CInt(FirstNumTextBox.Text)
        fiveNumbers(1) = CInt(SecondNumTextBox.Text)
        fiveNumbers(2) = CInt(ThirdNumTextBox.Text)
        fiveNumbers(3) = CInt(FourthNumTextBox.Text)
        fiveNumbers(4) = CInt(FifthNumTextBox.Text)
    End If

    'For i As Integer = 4 To 0 Step -1
    'fiveNumbers(i) = CInt(CInt(ReverseTextBox.Text).ToString)
    'Next

End Sub
Function average(fiveNumbers() As Integer) As Double
    average = (fiveNumbers(0) + fiveNumbers(1) + fiveNumbers(2) _
        + fiveNumbers(3) + fiveNumbers(4)) / 5
    Return average

    For i As Integer = 0 To 4 Step 1
        If fiveNumbers(i) > average Then

        End If
    Next

End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Being an homework assignement I prefer to just give some hints. After collecting the five numbers you need to call the function that calculates the average getting the return value. That function just need to perform the average calc and not other duties. Once  you get back the average you could checks your numbers to find the ones that are higher than average and print them somewhere on your forms (a listbox is simple enough for this)

Comment: I do agree with you, and that's appreciated so I still learn some here. My biggest problem seems to actually printing from the button click, I'm not sure how to display my array in the listbox which I have in my Form

Comment: http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/listbox-control-in-vb.net

Comment: @Steve This ended up being extremely helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also use Integer.TryParse() instead of the check IsNumeric and casting with CInt.